# Upgrading from EC2 M1.large instance to M4,2xlarge

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking to upgrade my current **M1.large Windows SQL Standard** instance to **M4.2xlarge Window SQL Express**.

I need to do this upgrade as I now have a higher performance requirement for the instance and also the SQL Express instance is way cheaper.

I am just wondering what would be the best approach for me to tackle this? The obvious issue here is the SQL database engine, as I am going from SQL standard to SQL express.

One of options is to create a new instance and manually rebuild the whole instance, but I want to keep the efforts minimum... I do have loads of data in the SQL database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Express is a limited version of SQL server. Its limited to 1 GB of memory and 4 Cores. Upgrading your instances size but downgrading SQL server wont get you anymore performance.

You will need to stay with Standard if you expect to get the performance of the new instance. All you need to do is shut it down, change the size and start it back up again.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. After doing some more diggings I find that it's impossible to change the instance type from SQL Standard to SQL Express. I will have to create a new instance and build it from scratch. Your comments around performance are correct, however the cost incurred from SQL is pretty high.